# How to get ranking based on Total Revenue(net_ph)?

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: Here's the output i want, you can see i have rank columns in excel]

The image above is the output i want, i want it to have ranking based on 'Total Sum of Net Revenue(net_ph)'

MY CODE IN PHP

```
SELECT artist, label, SUM(net_ph) as net_ph from believe_tb where  accounts_of='$cid2' group by artist, label
```

QUERY OUTPUT(NO RANKING)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the query like below:

```
select artist, label,
       RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(net_ph) desc) as ranking,
       SUM(net_ph) as net_ph
from believe_tb
group by artist, label;
```

Hope this helps.
More on RANK() funciton : https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-rank-function/

Comment: @Vayne if the answer resolved your issue, please accept the answer.